# Problem with .Get href link using scraper?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, get, href

So I am trying to follow a video tutorial that is just a bit outdated. In the video, using     `href = links[idx].get('href')` grabs the link, however if I use it here, it won't work. It just says none. If I just type     `.getText()` it will grab the title.

The element for the entire href and title is `<a href="https://mullvad.net/nl/blog/2023/2/2/stop-the-proposal-on-mass-surveillance-of-the-eu/">Stop the proposal on mass surveillance of the EU</a>`

Here's my code:

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/news')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('.titleline')
votes = soup.select('.score')

def create_custom_hn(links, votes):
    hn = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        title = links[idx].getText()
        href = links[idx].get('href')
        print(href)
        #hn.append({'title': title, 'link': href})
    return hn

print(create_custom_hn(links, votes))`
```

I tried to grab the link using     `.get('href')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select your elements more specific and avoid using different `lists` there is no need for that and you have to ensure that they will have same length.

You could get all information in one go, selecting the `<tr>` with class `athing` and its next sibling.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/news').text)

data = []
for i in soup.select('.athing'):

    data.append({
        'title' : i.select_one('span a').text,
        'link' : i.select_one('span a').get('href'),
        'score' : list(i.next_sibling.find('span').stripped_strings)[0]
    })
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Stop the proposal on mass surveillance of the EU',
  'link': 'https://mullvad.net/nl/blog/2023/2/2/stop-the-proposal-on-mass-surveillance-of-the-eu/',
  'score': '287 points'},
 {'title': 'Bay 12 Games has made $7M from the Steam release of Dwarf Fortress',
  'link': 'http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=181354.0',
  'score': '416 points'},
 {'title': "Google's OSS-Fuzz expands fuzz-reward program to $30000",
  'link': 'https://security.googleblog.com/2023/02/taking-next-step-oss-fuzz-in-2023.html',
  'score': '31 points'},
 {'title': "Connecticut Parents Arrested for Letting Kids Walk to Dunkin' Donuts",
  'link': 'https://reason.com/2023/01/30/dunkin-donuts-parents-arrested-kids-cops-freedom/',
  'score': '225 points'},
 {'title': 'Ronin 2.0 – open-source Ruby toolkit for security research and development',
  'link': 'https://ronin-rb.dev/blog/2023/02/01/ronin-2-0-0-finally-released.html',
  'score': '62 points'},...]
```