# How to parse links from website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get links from the first 30 articles from Hacker News website (https://news.ycombinator.com),but instead of only getting links of those particular websites, I'm getting some unnecessary data between them that I don't know how to get rid off or avoid.

This is the code I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests
response=requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com")
yc_webpage=response.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(yc_webpage,"lxml")
article_tag=soup.find_all(name="span",class_="titleline")
a_tags=soup.find_all("a")
tags=[]
for tag in a_tags:
    tags.append(tag["href"])
print(tags)
```

And the result I'm getting is:

```
 ['https://news.ycombinator.com', 'news', 'newest', 'front', 'newcomments', 'ask', 'show', 'jobs', 'submit', 'login?goto=news', 'vote?id=34866668&how=up&goto=news', 'https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/96864/GRADU-1428493916.pdf', 'from?site=tuni.fi', 'user?id=kklisura', 'item?id=34866668', 'hide?id=34866668&goto=news', 'item?id=34866668', 'vote?id=34865614&how=up&goto=news', 'http://oldvcr.blogspot.com/2023/02/dusting-off-dreamcast-linux.html', 'from?site=oldvcr.blogspot.com', 'user?id=todsacerdoti', 'item?id=34865614', 'hide?id=34865614&goto=news', 'item?id=34865614', 'vote?id=34864753&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.thelancet.com/journals/ebiom/article/PIIS2352-3964(23)00026-9/fulltext', 'from?site=thelancet.com', 'user?id=avodonosov', 'item?id=34864753', 'hide?id=34864753&goto=news', 'item?id=34864753', 'vote?id=34865768&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.infoq.com/news/2023/02/aws-policy-language-cedar/', 'from?site=infoq.com', 'user?id=msolujic', 'item?id=34865768', 'hide?id=34865768&goto=news', 'item?id=34865768', 'vote?id=34846709&how=up&goto=news', 'https://github.com/SuperIlu/DOjS', 'from?site=github.com/superilu', 'user?id=graderjs', 'item?id=34846709', 'hide?id=34846709&goto=news', 'item?id=34846709', 'vote?id=34866148&how=up&goto=news', 'http://english.news.cn/20221210/865dca4b89474d109a57a5957277fba1/c.html', 'from?site=news.cn', 'user?id=xrayarx', 'item?id=34866148', 'hide?id=34866148&goto=news', 'item?id=34866148', 'vote?id=34842962&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/CYN7swrefEss4e3Qe/childhoods-of-exceptional-people', 'from?site=lesswrong.com', 'user?id=lxm', 'item?id=34842962', 'hide?id=34842962&goto=news', 'item?id=34842962', 'vote?id=34837111&how=up&goto=news', 'https://blog.luap.info/your-b2b-startup-will-stop-innovating-the-day-you-give-power-to-product-managers.html', 'from?site=luap.info', 'user?id=polote', 'item?id=34837111', 'hide?id=34837111&goto=news', 'item?id=34837111', 'vote?id=34859979&how=up&goto=news', 'https://lethain.com/eng-strategies/', 'from?site=lethain.com', 'user?id=kiyanwang', 'item?id=34859979', 'hide?id=34859979&goto=news', 'item?id=34859979', 'vote?id=34864701&how=up&goto=news', 'https://geoffgraham.me/goodbye-css-tricks/', 'from?site=geoffgraham.me', 'user?id=tagawa', 'item?id=34864701', 'hide?id=34864701&goto=news', 'item?id=34864701', 'vote?id=34862424&how=up&goto=news', 'http://www.infiltration.org/', 'from?site=infiltration.org', 'user?id=almog', 'item?id=34862424', 'hide?id=34862424&goto=news', 'item?id=34862424', 'vote?id=34863784&how=up&goto=news', 'https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05331', 'from?site=arxiv.org', 'user?id=signa11', 'item?id=34863784', 'hide?id=34863784&goto=news', 'item?id=34863784', 'vote?id=34846606&how=up&goto=news', 'https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/', 'from?site=explained-from-first-principles.com', 'user?id=surprisetalk', 'item?id=34846606', 'hide?id=34846606&goto=news', 'item?id=34846606', 'vote?id=34863867&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-our-reality-may-be-a-sum-of-all-possible-realities-20230206/', 'from?site=quantamagazine.org', 'user?id=nnx', 'item?id=34863867', 'hide?id=34863867&goto=news', 'item?id=34863867', 'vote?id=34860164&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell', 'from?site=destroyallsoftware.com', 'user?id=kachnuv_ocasek', 'item?id=34860164', 'hide?id=34860164&goto=news', 'item?id=34860164', 'vote?id=34864058&how=up&goto=news', 'https://pomax.github.io/are-we-flying/', 'from?site=pomax.github.io', 'user?id=sebg', 'item?id=34864058', 'hide?id=34864058&goto=news', 'item?id=34864058', 'vote?id=34860655&how=up&goto=news', 'https://grifel.dev/decentralization/', 'from?site=grifel.dev', 'user?id=michalwarda', 'item?id=34860655', 'hide?id=34860655&goto=news', 'item?id=34860655', 'vote?id=34863903&how=up&goto=news', 'https://rife2.com/', 'from?site=rife2.com', 'user?id=hacktember', 'item?id=34863903', 'hide?id=34863903&goto=news', 'item?id=34863903', 'vote?id=34841274&how=up&goto=news', 'https://thelog.farm/2023/02/17/only-debate-the-non-linear/', 'from?site=thelog.farm', 'user?id=digb', 'item?id=34841274', 'hide?id=34841274&goto=news', 'item?id=34841274', 'vote?id=34865695&how=up&goto=news', 'item?id=34865695', 'user?id=the-mitr', 'item?id=34865695', 'hide?id=34865695&goto=news', 'item?id=34865695', 'vote?id=34866070&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-debug-probe-a-plug-and-play-debug-kit-for-12/', 'from?site=raspberrypi.com', 'user?id=schappim', 'item?id=34866070', 'hide?id=34866070&goto=news', 'item?id=34866070', 'vote?id=34859102&how=up&goto=news', 'https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.2022.09.25a.pdf', 'from?site=kernel.org', 'user?id=eric_khun', 'item?id=34859102', 'hide?id=34859102&goto=news', 'item?id=34859102', 'vote?id=34855489&how=up&goto=news', 'https://lareviewofbooks.org/article/maigrets-jurisdiction/', 'from?site=lareviewofbooks.org', 'user?id=overwhelm', 'item?id=34855489', 'hide?id=34855489&goto=news', 'item?id=34855489', 'vote?id=34858691&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.facebook.com/4/posts/good-morning-and-new-product-announcement-this-week-were-starting-to-roll-out-me/10114993498750111/', 'from?site=facebook.com', 'user?id=chirau', 'item?id=34858691', 'hide?id=34858691&goto=news', 'item?id=34858691', 'vote?id=34855331&how=up&goto=news', 'https://blog.joren.ga/less-known-c', 'from?site=joren.ga', 'user?id=jandeboevrie', 'item?id=34855331', 'hide?id=34855331&goto=news', 'item?id=34855331', 'vote?id=34855136&how=up&goto=news', 'https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html', 'from?site=beyond3d.com', 'user?id=tmsln', 'item?id=34855136', 'hide?id=34855136&goto=news', 'item?id=34855136', 'vote?id=34853524&how=up&goto=news', 'https://phys.org/news/2023-02-contents-fossils-reconstructed-nondestructively.html', 'from?site=phys.org', 'user?id=wglb', 'item?id=34853524', 'hide?id=34853524&goto=news', 'item?id=34853524', 'vote?id=34862432&how=up&goto=news', 'https://research.ibm.com/blog/AI-supercomputer-Vela-GPU-cluster', 'from?site=ibm.com', 'user?id=rbanffy', 'item?id=34862432', 'hide?id=34862432&goto=news', 'item?id=34862432', 'vote?id=34864589&how=up&goto=news', 'https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/controlnet-and-stable-diffusion-a-game-changer-for-ai-image-generation-83555cb942fc', 'from?site=uxdesign.cc', 'user?id=belltaco', 'item?id=34864589', 'hide?id=34864589&goto=news', 'item?id=34864589', 'vote?id=34860936&how=up&goto=news', 'https://www.samdickie.me/writing/experiment-1-creating-a-landing-page-using-ai-tools-no-code', 'from?site=samdickie.me', 'user?id=thisdickie', 'item?id=34860936', 'hide?id=34860936&goto=news', 'item?id=34860936', '?p=2', 'newsguidelines.html', 'newsfaq.html', 'lists', 'https://github.com/HackerNews/API', 'security.html', 'https://www.ycombinator.com/legal/', 'https://www.ycombinator.com/apply/', 'mailto:hn@ycombinator.com']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with .Get href link using scraper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324956/problem-with-get-href-link-using-scraper)

Answer (score 2):

You searched for all 'a' tags in website, not 'a' tags in article_tag.

So in for loop I added another instance of BeautifulSoup that will search for 'a' in individual 'article tag'.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com")
yc_webpage = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(yc_webpage, "lxml")
article_tag = soup.find_all(name="span", class_="titleline")
tags = []
for tag in article_tag:
    tag = BeautifulSoup(str(tag), 'lxml').find("a")['href']
    tags.append(tag)
print(tags)
```

Output:

```
['https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/96864/GRADU-1428493916.pdf', 'https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Exploration/Terrae_Novae_Europe_s_exploration_vision', 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22663351/', 'https://www.troyhunt.com/down-the-cloudflare-stripe-owasp-rabbit-hole-a-tale-of-6-rabbits-deep/', 'https://nltimes.nl/2023/01/25/amsterdam-supermarket-offers-free-groceries-life-coach-struggling-families', 'https://jobs.lever.co/buildzoom', 'https://www.thelancet.com/journals/ebiom/article/PIIS2352-3964(23)00026-9/fulltext', 'http://oldvcr.blogspot.com/2023/02/dusting-off-dreamcast-linux.html', 'https://www.infoq.com/news/2023/02/aws-policy-language-cedar/', 'https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/CYN7swrefEss4e3Qe/childhoods-of-exceptional-people', 'https://github.com/qaware/protocurl', 'https://github.com/SuperIlu/DOjS', 'https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/acquisitions/acquisition-process/', 'http://english.news.cn/20221210/865dca4b89474d109a57a5957277fba1/c.html', 'https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html', 'https://www.universetoday.com/160181/esa-is-building-an-early-warning-system-for-dangerous-asteroids/#more-160181', 'http://www.infiltration.org/', 'https://geoffgraham.me/goodbye-css-tricks/', 'https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/', 'https://rife2.com/', 'item?id=34865695', 'https://pomax.github.io/are-we-flying/', 'https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-our-reality-may-be-a-sum-of-all-possible-realities-20230206/', 'https://blog.luap.info/your-b2b-startup-will-stop-innovating-the-day-you-give-power-to-product-managers.html', 'https://thelog.farm/2023/02/17/only-debate-the-non-linear/', 'https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-debug-probe-a-plug-and-play-debug-kit-for-12/', 'https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05331', 'https://www.thepianofiles.com/the-valse-melancolique/', 'https://blog.joren.ga/less-known-c', 'https://phys.org/news/2023-02-contents-fossils-reconstructed-nondestructively.html']
```